# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Not open, not uninstall . Error :CLR20r3 System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on windows server 2012 R. When I open or uninstall it give to me Error like this:

> Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
>     Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
>     Problem Signature 02: 14.0.25420.1
>     Problem Signature 03: 57685d85
>     Problem Signature 04: WindowsBase
>     Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1087.0
>     Problem Signature 06: 583e614d
>     Problem Signature 07: 103
>     Problem Signature 08: 8
>     Problem Signature 09: System.DllNotFoundException
>     OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
>     Locale ID:    1055
>     Additional Information 1: deb9
>     Additional Information 2: deb969eb60886f932b093dbcbe745886
>     Additional Information 3: 1474
>     Additional Information 4: 147467a424cf9863af093715e7db7c9f

Comment: The question should have more details like, what version of Visual Studio 2015? Enterprise, Professional? Also which Windows OS version are you getting this?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standart and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Comment: can you try on Windows 10?

Comment: I user on Windows 10 no problem. 2 days a go there is no problem.